# How do i copy existing files to an existing folder using shutil

Tags: python, image, operating-system, copy, shutil

I'm trying to copy images to a local directory for my program to use later on.

this is the syntax i have:

```
import shutil
import os
path = 'C:\t1\x.txt' 
source = os.listdir(path)
destination = "C:\t2" #pre-existing folder
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        shutil.copy(files,destination)
```

The error i get says:

> (unicode error) 'unicodescape' codec cant decode bytes in position 5-6: truncated \xXX escape.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one of the following:

```
path = r'C:\t1\x.txt'
```

or

```
path = 'C:\\t1\\x.txt'
```

or as Bakuriu pointed out

```
path = 'C:/t1/x.txt'
```

And the same for `destination`

The issue is that the `\` character causes Python to interpret the string differently.  So you can either tell it to treat the string as raw text (`r''`) or give it the `\` literal, which is `\\`

Alternatively, you could make your script platform independent by using `os.path.join()` to construct folder paths.  This will always construct them with the correct delimeters for whatever platform you're running on.  Be aware of this from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html):

> Note that on Windows, since there is a current directory for each
>   drive, os.path.join("c:", "foo") represents a path relative to the
>   current directory on drive C: (c:foo), not c:\foo.

Comment: Note that Windows path *can* use `/` instead of ```\``` as a directory separator. You can use: `C:/t1/x.txt` for example. All the APIs can use both separators (with the exception of the paths that begin with `\\?`. Some *applications* may fail to handle them as separators, but since python provides access to the API there isn't any problem with `/` in the paths).

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks for that, I've updated the answer to include it